# Azure: Load Local Storage from Blog Storage

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, azure, local-storage

I notice that with my Azure VM I get a certain amount of SSD "Local Storage".

I also see a ton of references online to this only being temporary storage, however I have a large amount of static data I'd like to pre-load into this space to take advantage of the speed.

Is there a way to take a Blob and load it into Local Storage, or any other way to pre-load local storage?

Answer (score 0):

> I also see a ton of references online to this only being temporary storage

You are able to select SSD as your data disk when you are creating your VM. But it is more expensive then the VM using HDD.

[image: My Azure]

Here is the pricing calculator for Azure VM.
[Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)